# How to use objects in an array (php)?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with objects and I want to get an item of an object. How to do it?

My array looks like this:

```
<?php
    array(
        [0]=>Object(
            [ID]=>1
            [name]=>firstname
        )
        [1]=>Object(
            [ID]=>2
            [name]=>secondname
        )
        [2]=>Object(
            [ID]=>3
            [name]=>thirdname
        )
    )
?>
```

So I want to get the "secondname", but I don't know how.
I know that I can get the whole object by array[1] but I don't know how to get objects [name].

Comment: Have you actually tried solving this?

Comment: I guess it's an easy question but I'm inexperienced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it by using

```
foreach($a as $object){  
  echo $object->name;
}
```

You can get the secondname by using

```
echo $a[1]->name;
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/sdT7E

Comment: Thanks for your help but this way I get all the [name] items and not a specific one.

Comment: @EmmanuelRichman you can apply a condition inside `foreach` to get the specific

Answer (score 0):

Simple,Sometimes u can use type casting ,object convert to array

```
$array=(array) $object;

print_r($array)
```